# Limsup, Liminf,...

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

I have this exercise and I don't know how to solve it
Let $(A_n)_n \subset (E,d),(B_n)\subset (F,d')$ 2 sequence of sets from a metric space,and $f: E \rightarrow F$ a continuous aplication .

Prove that :

1)$\displaystyle f(\limsup_{n\to\infty} A_n) \subset \limsup_{n\to\infty} f(A_n)$

2)$\displaystyle f(\liminf_{n\to\infty} A_n) ‎\subset‎ \liminf_{n\to\infty} f(A_n)$

3)$\displaystyle \limsup_{n\to\infty}f^{-1}(B_n) \subset f^{-1}(\limsup_{n\to\infty} B_n)$

4)$\displaystyle \liminf_{n\to\infty}f^{-1}(B_n) \subset f^{-1}(\liminf_{n\to\infty} B_n)$

with:
$x\in \overline\lim(A_n) \Rightarrow$
$ x\in \displaystyle\bigcap_{\varepsilon>0}\bigcap_{N>0}\bigcup_{n\geq N} (A_n)_\varepsilon \Rightarrow \forall \varepsilon >0, \forall N>0, \exists n\geq N ;d(x,A_n)< \varepsilon$

help me please ,
thank you .

Comment: Metrics and continuity are irrelevant here, this is a purely set-theoretical result. // What did you try?

Comment: @Did I believe the continuity is relevant. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior#General_set_convergence for definitions.

Comment: @ferson2020 Now that the OP modified their post, continuity is involved. Before that, a quite usual interpretation was that [it was not](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior#Special_case:_discrete_metric).

Comment: 1) i can say: $x\in f(\limsup A_n) \Rightarrow \exists y\in \limsup A_n , x=f(y) \Rightarrow \forall \varepsilon >0, \forall N>0, \exists n\geq N ;d(y,A_n)< \varepsilon ,x=f(y)$ as f is continuous then $\forall \varepsilon >0, \forall N>0, \exists n\geq N ;d(f(y),f(A_n))< \varepsilon$ then $x=f(y) \in \limsup f(A_n)$ , it's correct ? please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: See, [Own Lecture Notes Functional Analysis](http://www.win.tue.nl/~rvhassel/Onderwijs/2DE08-0809/OwnLectureNotesFA.pdf). Theorem 2.15.1, p17.

Comment: See , this is for multivalued set :$x\in f(\limsup A_n) \Rightarrow \exists y\in \limsup A_n , x=f(y)$ ,y\in \limsup A_n \Rightarrow \liminf d(y,A_n)=0$

Comment: 1) i can say :$x\in f(\limsup A_n) \Rightarrow \exists y\in \limsup A_n , x=f(y) \Rightarrow \forall \varepsilon >0, \forall N>0, \exists n\geq N ;d(y,A_n)< \varepsilon ,x=f(y) $ as $f$ is continuous then $\forall \varepsilon >0, \forall N>0, \exists n\geq N ;d(f(y),f(A_n))< \varepsilon $ then $x=f(y) \in \limsup f(A_n)$ , it's correct ?

Comment: I edited my post because the last refrence is about sequence of numbers but this is about sequence of sets. see Theorem 2.15.1, p17 with usual definition of limSup and liminf, continuous of $f$ is irrelevant, but with your definition i am not sure, that what you write is true.